# Where should i declare the button of different layout?

Tags: java, android, button, layout

I've made a calculator apps and I'm trying to create an about page showing some information.
[image]
The OK button will be coded setContentView(originallayout.xml) to return to the calculator layout.

Where should i put these codes to declare the OK button?

`private Button btnOK;`

`btnOK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOK);`

`btnok.setOnClickListener(OKListener);`

I tried to put these code just below where i did for the buttons at the main layout but the apps just stopped after launch.

`07-18 09:39:43.290: E/AndroidRuntime(6984): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hychentsa.calculator/com.hychentsa.calculator.CalculatorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: you are initializing a button from a different view hierarchy? You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using setContentView() to change screens, you should have separate activities. Then, in your about activity, you can simply call finish() on button click to go back to the main activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 1):

if your layout doesn't content the id of the button (in your case **`btnOK`**),  Eclipse throws NullPointerException - it can not find it in your layout's content.
So when you set your layout (or menu), it must content the id btnOK. Check it!

Put your button initialization **after** `setContentView(R.layout.your_about_layout_name);`
Put all this code in

```
Button btnOK;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.about);

btnOK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
btnok.setOnClickListener(OKListener);
}
```

***Update:*** 
Look at the answer of invertigo:
It's wrong to change the layout when you click on the button.
You have to do it this way:

**CalculatorActivity**

```
public class CalculatorActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.calculator_black);

// initialization of your views stays here
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.calculator_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.your_id_to_go_in_about_activity:
                Intent intent = new Intent(CalculatorActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);

                // put some extras if you need to send information from this page to the
                // AboutActivity page with this code: intent.putExtra();
                startActivity(intent); // with this code you go to AboutActivity
                return true;
            case R.id.theme:
                // Do Something with the theme
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Now, the place for your initialization of OKButton is in new class, lets call it
**AboutActivity**
here you can put my earlier code:

```
public class AboutActivity extends Activity{

Button btnOK;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.about);

btnOK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
btnok.setOnClickListener(OKListener);
}

 // and the listener for your OK button have to look like this:
OnClickListener OKListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something here if you need
            finish(); // with finish() you are returning to the previous page
            // which is CalculatorActivity
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work...
Actually when i open the apps it will set the layout as `R.layout.calculator_black`, after i click the "about" item of the menu, it will set layout to `R.layout.about` , this layout contains a Button btnOK. I would like to set this button so that it set the layout back to R.layout.calculator_black when clicked.

Comment: Did you try my code after the update I've done? It should work.